# What is the purpose of adding brackets at the end of this reduce method?

Tags: javascript, reduce

I am reading Eloquent Javascript and I am on chapter 5, Higher order functions. One of the Problems at the end was to flatten an array of multiple arrays. The Book solution gives the solution as an arrow function, and it has brackets at the end of the line of code. I want to know why they have to be there because i wrote the same code without the brackets and it returned the same value. I just wanna know why we use the brackets so I can understand the reduce method better, and not mess anything up in the future. Here is the 2 versions, they both work.

I looked through various forums, Stack, MDN, w3, could not find an explanation.

```
var arrays = [[1,2,3],[4,5],[6,7],[8,9]];

console.log(arrays.reduce(function(a, b) { return a.concat(b)},[]));
// Brackets----------------------------------------------------^^^
console.log(arrays.reduce(function(a, b) { return a.concat(b)}));
// No Brackets-----------------------------------------------^^^

//result = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

So the result is the same for both, but I know that there has to be a reason that these brackets are here, I want to know why and what the purpose of them is. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Reduce is a higher order function if you want your final output to be array you use `[]` if you want object you use `{}`

Comment: Compare the two again with an empty `arrays`. They'll likely differ. The starting accumulator is returned if the list being reduced over is empty; or at least that's the case in most languages I know. The second will probably cause an error, or return `undefined` or something.

Comment: By the way, you should never concatenate arrays like this. It’s super inefficient. `arrays.flat()` instead in current JS.

Comment: `arr.reduce(callback[, ***initialValue***])` --->>>  https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Syntax

Comment: It's as simple as reading the [documentation of `Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

Answer (score 2):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

initialValue:

Value to use as the first argument to the first call of the callback. If no initial value is supplied, the first element in the array will be used. Calling reduce() on an empty array without an initial value is an error.

Example where the initialValue matters:

```
var fruit = ['apple', 'banana', 'banana', 'apple', 'banana', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple'];

console.log(fruit.reduce(function(a, b) { a[b]++; return a; },{apple: 0, banana: 0}));
// { apple: 5, banana: 3 }

console.log(fruit.reduce(function(a, b) { a[b]++; return a; }));
// apple
```

So you see in this scenario, if I give a nice initial value, I get what I want - the count of each type of fruit. Not giving an initial value here just makes the code randomly spit out the word apple.

Comment: Yeah, so the only reason I'm conflating is cuz that is the solution. I do realize that the last number is the starting point. When I get home I'll check what the first guy said about the bracket meaning it's an array.

Comment: I've added an example where the initialValue matters. Does that give you a better idea of it's purpose?